# Display Image using asset path or local file path

Tags: ios, image, swift

I'm trying to display a table of images from the camera roll using swift. I have the asset path:

`assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=123456789&ext=JPG`

and the local file path:

`/Users/johndoe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1932149090125/data/Containers/Data/Application/11451-54365436-34563-2345-232342364/Documents/asset.JPG`

I don't know what function to use to create a UIImage.

I've tried `UIImage(data: NSdata)`, and `UIImage(contentsOfFile: String)` with no success.

**Code**:
Inside my UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath function, I'm looping through a database that has the cell's asset path and local file path.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "/Users/johndoe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/123455678/data/Containers/Data/Application/124536432342364/Documents/asset.JPG")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    cell.thumbnailImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

Comment: Have you tried `UIImage(named: "imageName")`?

Comment: @bsarr007 oops,  forgot to mention that one too. thanks for pointing that out. but yes, i've tried that too. "named" only seems to work with files that are saved in my directory and doesn't pull from the camera roll. unless im executing incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to display a table of images from the camera roll using swift

Well, it's an elaborate business. You have to use PhotoKit. Obtain the photo as a PHAsset, and call `PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset` to get the actual image. The image arrives asynchronously and can arrive multiple times as the quality of the image improves, so you have to be prepared for that.

Comment: You should watch the WWDC 2014 video on Photo Kit to learn more.

Comment: Ah I see, so the asset path i received from UIImagePickerController will not suffice.

Comment: UIImagePickerController is fine for images selected in the image picker controller, because it supplies the images to you directly. But that is not what you asked. If you use UIImagePickerController then in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` you are given `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]`. But that is not going to get you "a table of images from the camera roll", which is what you asked about.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function, which is called when a picture has been selected in the imagePickerController, see below. Make sure your ViewController uses the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol.

Then in my .m-file I have the function belonging to that protocol:

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info { // Comes here after each picture, photographed or picked

```
UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

etc, etc
}

Comment: i saw this as well in swift: ' photoImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage' i guess my next question would be. how do you convert the information i have to a  UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage